# Notify about change in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [monitoring mysql for changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696655/monitoring-mysql-for-changes)

I have a MySQL database and i want to have a notification for changes. I'm using JDBC (Java) and want to refresh the UI when data is added to my table from another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to poll the MySQL data base and update when it changes. Or have a monitor daemon that uses some kind of Socket to push update notifications out to clients.

Comment: i don't want to add a timer thread, that query to database ...

Comment: do you have any link for tutorial about it?

Comment: Then its not possible, you're looking for triggers, but i dont think MySQL can make a web call from a trigger.

Comment: Maybe this? https://blogs.oracle.com/kay/entry/calling_java_code_in_mysql

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a few thoughts to what j_mcnally said. (BTW good reading in the SO question he linked to).

Can you shed some more light on what you mean by "data is added to my table from another program." A program you control? A program you can change? Are we talking TOAD or some other dB tool? The more control over the access to that data you have the better solution you can come up with.

My off the cuff response would be to expose that data as services in the app so that all data manipulations are always going through the same "gatekeeper" (a la JPA's EntityManager) as your app does. This would make it trivial to implement a notification system for the UI.

You mentioned not wanting to add a timer thread... What about a simple table that does nothing but hold a last updated date and table name. Something quick you can run whenever the client makes a request to decide whether or not you want to reuse your existing data, or make a fresh call? You would need to run it in front of every request, but its not a loop on a timer, if that is what you had an issue with.